# Table with Unique Name Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of items that looks like roughly:

```
[
    {name: "john", task: "dig"},
    {name: "john", task: "swim"},
    {name: "john", task: "eat"},
    {name: "paul", task: "dig"},
]
```

I want to create a table so that the header would have the name and then the tasks underneath so for example

```
john       paul
dig        dig
swim
eat
```

So somebody here kindly told me of the reduce function however I'm still having issues in getting this to appear in that above way.

What I'm lost with is once I've applied the reduce function so say:

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(table, element)
{
    if(!table[element.name])
    {
        table[element.name] = [];
    }
    table[element.name].push(element.task);
    return table;
}, {});
// For demo:
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

How do I get the table to look as I want to above?

Comment: Why not define the tasks in an array within the object? {name: "john", tasks: ["dig","swim","eat"].....}. Would make the rest of your job a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They gave you a nice solution, I also think Array.prototype.reduce() is the cleanest way to go.

Now that you have the data organised, let's go for the styling.

We'll iterate the object finding the different (two in this case) *properties*. For each one we'll create a `div` and `ul` elements.

Then we'll iterate the *value* of the *property* (an *Array*) and create a `li` element for each one.

Last step, we'll make the `div` elements to `float: left;` to keep them in parallel.

Of course, you could also use a `table` element.

```js
var arr = [
    {name: 'john', task: 'dig'},
    {name: 'john', task: 'swim'},
    {name: 'john', task: 'eat'},
    {name: 'paul', task: 'dig'},
];
  
var result = arr.reduce(function(table, element) {
    if(!table[element.name]) { table[element.name] = []; }
    table[element.name].push(element.task);
    return table;
}, {});

$('body').append('<p>My data: ' + JSON.stringify(result) + '<p><hr>');

for (var key in result) {
  var html = '<div>' + key + '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < result[key].length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + result[key][i] + '</li>';
  }
  $('body').append(html + '</ul></div>');
}
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Approaching it step-by-step,

1. You would want to group your array by the names. This can be done simply by iterating over the array and converting your tasks into an array into a new object. Something like what @Dave suggested in the comment above.

Given your data, you group it into a `persons` object:

```
var data = [
        {name: "john", task: "dig"},
        {name: "john", task: "swim"},
        {name: "john", task: "eat"},
        {name: "paul", task: "dig"},
    ], persons = {}

data.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (! (elem.name in persons)) { persons[elem.name] = []; }
    persons[elem.name].push(elem.task);
});
```

This will transform your data into an object which will now look like this:

```
{john: Array[3], paul: Array[1]}
```

Where the keys are the names and values are the arrays of corresponding tasks.

2. In order to display this in a table, you need to divide the task into two steps. One where, you display the headers as `thead`. And then, you display the rows inside a `tbody`. Displaying headers is easy, as you just take the keys of the new object adding into a `td` which would then be appended to a `tr` and then appended to the `thead`.

Something like this:

```
tr = document.createElement('tr');
for (person in persons) {
    th = document.createElement('th');
    th.textContent = person;
    tr.appendChild(th);
    rows = persons[person].length > rows ? persons[person].length : rows;
}
thead.appendChild(tr); table.appendChild(thead);
```

Besides creating the header row, you also figure out the number of `tbody` rows that would be required. This can be calculated easily as the longest of the task arrays in each of the keys. You cache that into a `rows` variable in the above loop.

3. Having known the number of rows required, you now run a loop that many times creating a `tr` and appending to the `tbody`. For every row, you will then iterate over the keys of the `persons` object and create `td` for each of the tasks array index of which will correspond to the index of loop.

Something quick and dirty:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (person in persons) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = persons[person][i];
        tr.appendChild(td); 
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

4. All that remains now is to append the `table` you created to the `body` of your page (or a `div` for that matter).

Just a couple of `appendChild`s:

```
table.appendChild(tbody); document.body.appendChild(table);
```

That's it, you now have a table which is a transposition of your original data.

**Here is a complete working demo**:

```js
var data = [
        {name: "john", task: "dig"},
        {name: "john", task: "swim"},
        {name: "john", task: "eat"},
        {name: "paul", task: "dig"},
 ], 
    persons = {}, rows = 0, 
    table = document.createElement('table'), 
    thead = document.createElement('thead'), 
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody'), 
    tr, th, td
;

// iterate the data and transform into persons object
data.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (! (elem.name in persons)) { persons[elem.name] = []; }
    persons[elem.name].push(elem.task);
});


// create header row
tr = document.createElement('tr');
for (person in persons) {
    th = document.createElement('th');
    th.textContent = person;
    tr.appendChild(th);
    // calculate number of rows as longest of task array
 rows = persons[person].length > rows ? persons[person].length : rows;
}
thead.appendChild(tr); table.appendChild(thead);

// iterate for rows
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
 for (person in persons) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = persons[person][i];
        tr.appendChild(td); 
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

// append table to body
table.appendChild(tbody); document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid #ddd; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 4px; margin: 16px; }
```

And a fiddle to go with it: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n1n1xzdz/1/**

***Note***: *The above is a little crude example. While creating the rows, it is referencing tasks array indices which are out of bounds and will return `undefined`. However, DOM manipulation will on its own ignore that and leave the `textContent` empty for those cells. Ideally, you would be checking for those cases.*

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this. I ended up using both your answers. I used the table creation on yours and the reduce method from the below.

Comment: @userMod2: Great! By the way, IMO reduce is an overkill here. A simple iteration is enough.

Comment: Ah ok - in actual fact that data would contain 200 - 300 items. Is that still overkill?

Comment: @userMod2: Actually what I meant to say was that reduce is convenient in cases where you need to operate on previous and current values in an iteration, processing them with an accumulator and seeding the accumulator in one go. In your use-case a simple iterator is enough. However, that shouldn't make much difference. Whatever, you are more comfortable with. :)